# statistics service recomendation

Tags: statistics

does anyone know of a good statistics service for a widget I'm developing?
my requirements are 
1.have the ability to get hundreds of thousands of events per day.
2.API to get results and registering events.
3.near real time results.

thnx
michael

Answer (score 0):

Try www.getclicky.com, it meets all your requirements.

Comment: i am now using it but it limits the amount of clicks we can use per day. it wont stand the load